# How to check whether the document is editing or not in OWA?

Tags: office-web-apps

I can find `CheckedOutByUser` or `LockedByUser`, but these properties returns `null` even the document is opened in OWA.

Is there any way to know whether the document is opened/been editing by anyone using OWA?

Answer (score 0):

Use checkout type to find the File is Checked Out or not.

```
   if (file.CheckOutType != CheckOutType.None)
   {
       //Do Some Code if the file is CheckOut
   }
```

Comment: Really is this will work? Because @Daniel is talking about OWA.

Comment: This does not help my issue. Thanks Mohamed, but I need a solution for OWA.